# Error: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Currently I am having problem about has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.
I've tried to fix it in many ways but it still doesn't seem to work.
Hope someone can show me how to fix it.
My code:
File Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
...
    services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy(name: "AllowAnyOrigin",
                        builder =>
                        {
                            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader();
                    });
                });
      ...
  }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app){
   ...
    app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");
   ...
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnableCors("AllowAnyOrigin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeInviteSponsors([FromForm] ChangeInviteSponsorsModel changeInviteSponsorsModel)
    {
        string userId = User.GetUserId();
        return Ok(await _inviteSponsorsService.ChangeInviteSponsors(changeInviteSponsorsModel, userId));
    }
```

**Error:** *Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:5560/api/InviteSponsors/ChangeInviteSponsors' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

Help me please. Thank you!

Comment: See following : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `CORS policy violation` issue, try this.

Also, **the order** of connecting services in the `Configure` method is very important.

First, in the *ConfigureServices* method, the first method before controller mapping should be

```
services.AddCors();
```

Second, to allow CORS, change the `Configure` method. Add this code after the `UseRouting` and before *Middlewares* and *Controller* mappings.

```
app.UseCors(x => x
 .AllowAnyOrigin()
 .AllowAnyMethod()
 .AllowAnyHeader()
 .AllowCredentials());
```

*This will allow any requests from any external domains.*

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but it still doesn't work for me.
My case: Only 1 function failed: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
The rest all work normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance but it still doesn't work for me.
My case: Only 1 function failed: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
The rest all work normally.